# FCM: Handling Notification in background to get data message into the intent page (received notification)

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending a notification using the cloud functions to the users. when the user clicks on the notification it should redirect to the Intent page and displays the data message. I am getting a problem when the app is in background

> MyFirebaseMesssaging services class

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Map;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MY android fcm service";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        String FirstName = "0";
        String Amount = "0";
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            FirstName = remoteMessage.getData().get("Name");
            Amount = remoteMessage.getData().get("Amount");
            Log.d(TAG, "From:" + remoteMessage.getFrom());
            Log.d(TAG, "Notification MessageBody:" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            createNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),FirstName,Amount);
        }
    }
    private void createNotification(String messageBody, String FirstName, String amount) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( this,ReceivedNotification.class );
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("FirstName",FirstName);
        intent.putExtra("Amount",amount);
        PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this , 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Uri notificationSoundURI = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("deyaPay")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true )
                .setSound(notificationSoundURI)
                .setContentIntent(resultIntent)
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_player)
        // Add media control buttons that invoke intents in your media service
        //.addAction(R.drawable.accept, "Accept",) // #0
        //.addAction(R.drawable.ic_reject, "Reject", ResultActivity.class) ; // ;

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, mNotificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

> ReceivedNotification class(Intent Page)

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class ReceivedNotification extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView Name;
    private TextView amount;
    public static String TAG = "REceivved";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTitle("Received notifications");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.receivednotification);
        Name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        amount =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView14);
        Intent  i = getIntent();
        if (i != null && i.getExtras() != null) {
            Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
            String FirstName = extras.getString("FirstName");
            String amount1 = extras.getString("Amount");
            Name.setText(FirstName);
            amount.setText(amount1);

        }

        }

    }
}
```

> Cloud functions for sending notification

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const firestore = new Firestore();
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();
exports.splitting  = functions.firestore
    .document('deyaPayUsers/{authid}/Split/{authid1}/SentInvitations/{autoid}')
    .onWrite(event =>{
    var  id = event.params.authid;
    var dbref = db.collection('deyaPayUsers').doc(id);
    var na = dbref.FirstName;
    console.log(na);
    console.log(id);
    var id1 = event.params.authid1;
    var  splitid = event.params.autoid;
    var document = event.data.data();
    var phoneNumber = [];
    for(var k in document){
    phoneNumber.push(document[k].PhoneNumber);
    }
    console.log("The json data is " +phoneNumber);
    var ph1 = document.Invite1.PhoneNumber;
    var amount = document.Invite1.Amount;
    var a = amount.toString();
    console.log(a);
    console.log(document);
    console.log(ph1);
  var deyaPay = db.collection("deyaPayUsers");
  let phQuery = deyaPay.where('PhoneNumber','==',ph1)
.get()
   .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc=>{
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                       var userData = doc.data();
                       var userId = doc.id;
                       var FirstName = userData.FirstName;
                         console.log(FirstName);
                         var LastName = userData.LastName;
                          console.log(FirstName);
                       var FullName = FirstName + LastName;
                        console.log(FullName);
                       var Token = userData.FCMToken;
                       console.log(userId);
                       console.log("FCM Token for that phoneNumber" + Token);
                       console.log(userData.PhoneNumber);
                       console.log(ph1 + "Exist In DB");
```

> //This is for sending notification message

```
   let payload = {       
        notification: {
            title: "Message",
            body:  'request to pay ${(FirstName)}',
            sound: "default",


        },
        'data':{
                'Name':FirstName,
                'Amount':a
        }
    };
console.log(payload);
   return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(Token, payload).then((response)=> { // This method is used for returning the notification to a specific device
    console.log(Token);
      console.info("Successfully sent notification")
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.warn("Error sending notification " , error)
        });
                });

 }) .catch(err => {
                    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
                                   });

 });
```

> Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:name="com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay.GlobalAmount"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="deyaPay"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
            android:value="true" />
        <activity android:name="com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay.Signup" />
        <activity android:name="com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay.ResetPasswordActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay.EmailVerification" />
        <activity android:name="com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay.AddMoney"/>
        <activity android:name=".deyaPay"/>
        <activity android:name=".PaymentMethods"/>
        <activity android:name=".Stripe"/>
        <activity android:name=".ACH"/>
        <activity android:name=".ViewProfile"/>
        <activity android:name=".EditProfile"/>
        <activity android:name=".Split"/>
        <activity android:name=".Display"/>
        <activity android:name=".MessageReceived" />
        <activity android:name=".SentNotificationReceivedNotification"/>
        <activity android:name=".ReceivedNotification"/>
        <activity android:name=".SentNotification"/>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845174/4247543

Comment: Please share the exact error you are getting.Check with this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663601/open-a-specific-activity-from-firebase-notification

Comment: @Hema I am not getting any error when I click the notification It does not goes to the intended page

Answer (score -1):

When the app is in background, the android system handles the notification if it is a hybrid or notifcation. So the intent is passed to Laucnher activity, when user clicks the clicks notification. You can get the data by

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class ReceivedNotification extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView Name;
    private TextView amount;
    public static String TAG = "REceivved";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTitle("Received notifications");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.receivednotification);
        Name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        amount =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView14);
        Intent  i = getIntent();
        if(getIntent.hasExtra("Name")){
           Name.setText(getIntent.getStringExtra("Name"));
           amount.setText(getIntent.getStringExtra("Amount"));
        } else {
          (i != null && i.getExtras() != null) {
            Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
            String FirstName = extras.getString("FirstName");
            String amount1 = extras.getString("Amount");
            Name.setText(FirstName);
            amount.setText(amount1);

           }
        }    
    }
}
```

Change MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView Name;
    private TextView amount;
    public static String TAG = "REceivved";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTitle("Received notifications");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.receivednotification);
        if(getIntent.hasExtra("Name")){
           Name.setText(getIntent.getStringExtra("Name"));
           amount.setText(getIntent.getStringExtra("Amount"));
           sendNotificationIntent(getIntent.getStringExtra("Name"), getIntent.getStringExtra("Amount"));
        }    
    }

    private void sendNotificationIntent(String name, String amount){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReceivedNotification.class);
        intent.putExtra("Name", name);
        intent.putExtra("Amount", amount);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: I used these but it didn't works

Comment: Intent  i = getIntent();
        String datavalue = i.getStringExtra("Name");
        Name.setText(datavalue);
        String am = i.getStringExtra("Amount");
        amount.setText(am);

Comment: @LahariAreti check this ans https://stackoverflow.com/a/40955163/7666442

Comment: @NileshRathod I need the data message . In data payload I have 2 keys like Name and amount . I didnt understant these link

Comment: @LahariAreti check than ans you can send multiple values using it

Comment: @NileshRathod in these link getBody() is a default method or it extrct the body data in notification

Comment: @LahariAreti getBody() is for extrct the body data from notification

Comment: @Nilesh I need data message payload not the body message

Comment: @LahariAreti you can also pass  data message payload

Comment: can u add those lines of code

Comment: what are the keys of your data payload ?

Comment: Name  and Amount are keys

Comment: which is your launcher activity ?

Comment: is it Name or name ?

Comment: @ Muhammed ReceivedNotification is the launcher activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166439/discussion-between-muhammed-saneef-and-lahari-areti).

Comment: @MuhammedSaneef It is Name

Comment: if(getIntent.hasExtra("Name")) {
Name.setText(getIntent.getStringExtra("Name"));
 }

Comment: @MuhammedSaneef it does not works

Comment: could you send your notification payload, the one you send from firebase?

Comment: @MuhammedSaneef I have posted my cloud function for sending notification . check it once

Comment: Does it work when app is in the foreground?

Comment: Ya it is working in foreground and it displays the data as well

Comment: check if the edited code works

Comment: could you show the Manifest file ?

Comment: @MuhammedSaneef check I have added manifest file.

Comment: @LahariAreti Your launcher activity is MainActivity. So when you click the background notification, the intent is passed to MainActivity. So you will have to pass that intent from MainActivity to RtecevedNotificaition.

In MainActivity, check if you have your data payload and pass it to ReceivedNotification.

Comment: Its not a general case to put intents like that.

Comment: It should happen only when we receive notification and when the app is in background

Comment: @LahariAreti When the app is in background, android system passes intent to your MainActivity. Otherwise your intent will be received in ReceivedNotification.

Comment: Also, there is another way of doing this, you can change your backend notification sender to send only data messages.

Comment: @MuhammedSaneef last comment I did not understand

Comment: @LahariAreti Instead of sending a notification + data message from firebase, you can send data only message from firebase. You will have to send title, body, in the data payload

let payload = {       
        'data':{
                'Name':FirstName,
                'Amount':a,
        }
    };

Then your app will handle both background and foreground cases.

Comment: then user can see the notification . can u edit my post

Comment: But in this case, you will have to get the title of notification from the data payload. getData().get('title') and getData.get('body') for setting the notification title and body.